# Uber-style rideshare/taxi services in Russia?

Tags: russia, taxis, mobile-apps, uber, ride-sharing

What are my options for **rideshare/taxi apps in Russia**? I understand [Uber is in the process of pulling out](https://www.cnbc.com/2017/11/24/uber-and-yandex-taxi-merger-gets-legal-approval-in-russia.html), and only covered a few of the largest cities anyway. I'm specifically interested in Irkutsk, but happy to entertain broader answers.

Goal: an app that lets me specify pickup & dropoff locations without needing to speak Russian and offers clear pricing or at least a dependable estimate before I book.

Update: I used Yandex quite a bit and it worked very well. Just don't rely it outside the city: I was surprised to find that in both Taltsy and Listvyanka at least my operator had no signal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, there is [Yandex.Taxi](https://taxi.yandex.ru) that the article you linked mentions; basically they are now merging with Uber. They have their own app, moreover, they say that the standard Uber app will still work in Russia, allowing to order taxi from the merged company. They are available in Irkutsk, as well as in many other Russian cities. So you will be able to use your Uber app.

[Gett](https://gett.com/ru/) is another international taxi service that is available in many Russian cities including Irkutsk.

[Taxi Saturn](https://taxisaturn.ru/) is a Russian service that is also available in Irkutsk as well as in many other cities.

[Taxi Maxim](https://taximaxim.ru) is one more service. I've never used their app (only once booked via phone), but apparently they are available in many cities too.

There are also many other apps that allow to book a taxi; nowadays many local taxi services have their own app. You can even google for "taxi app Irkutsk" to see a great list of them.

---

Disclaimer: I am a Yandex (though not specifically Yandex.Taxi) employee.

Comment: There's also [Taxi Maxim](https://taximaxim.ru/) which should be available in many smaller cities.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is Taxi Maxim.
I am from Irkutsk and can tell you for sure that Taxi Maxim is the  most popular here and also perfectly fit your requirements.
Also we have Yandex and Gett. Yandex is Uber-style and is thriving though the Gett's time has gone and we don't hear from it anymore.